# GORM Querying multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, grails, join, collections, grails-orm

I am working with Grails and MongoDB. I have two domain classes User and AddWebsite. A User hasMany websites and each website belongs to a user. 
The domain classes are as follows:

```
class AddWebsite{
String website
User user
static belongsTo = [user: User]
static constraints = {
    website url:true
    user nullable:true
}
}
```

The Other domain class is as follows:

```
class User {
    String login
    String password
    static hasMany = [
        addWebsites: AddWebsite
    ]
    static mapping = {
        addWebsites cascade:"all-delete-orphan"
      }
    static constraints = {
        }
    }
```

I need to query the AddWebsite table based on the current logged in user and get the websites of that particular user. Can anyone suggest any approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You need to create a createCriteria List as follow

def c = AddWebsite.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {

           //find the user based on the relationship
             user {

                   ideq(userobj?.id.toLong())

              }

          //you can user projection here if u need a single value

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this approach. May not be most efficient but it works .

```
def showWebsites(){
    def p = User.findByLogin(session["user"].login)
    def websites = AddWebsite.findAllByUser(p['_id'])
    [websitesList: websites] 
}
```

And in my GSP I have:

```
<g:select name="websiteSelection" from="${websitesList.website} " />
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used MongoDB but since GORM supports it I assume an example query would do what you need:

`AddWebsite.findAllByUser(userObj)`

If you just wanted the website Strings then this should work:

`def userWebsites = AddWebsite.findAllByUser(userObj)*.website`

Where userWebsites will be a `List<String>`

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html for more info.

BTW, you don't need "User user" in your AddWebsite class since you've named "user" in your belongsTo.